# how to apply relevance feedback in SIFT algorithm

Tags: matlab, sift

I have function for calculating the keypoints from the image but as using SIFT it is not giving accurate results so will be using relevance feedback for that but i dont know how to append in this code?
This is code for SIFT:-

http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/43724-sift--scale-invariant-feature-transform

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean SIFT does not give accurate results? What is relevance feedback? This question is very unclear.

Comment: sorry in my project m retrieving the results that are similar to the query image by extracting and comparing the keypoints from sift.But the results of getting similar images are not that good .so i want to use relevance feedback??

Comment: I dont know what relevance feedback is, but you may want to look to "feature matching" techniques, very commonly used for SIFT feature point matching. There is a lot about it in the internet/stackoverflow